# How to close/remove QGIS welcome page (recent projects) with Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to close the QGIS welcome page with Python?

I have a permanently docked Python plugin, that uses showRubberBand to directly write into map canvas. Therefor I have to close/remove the welcome page first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches to that:

### Start a new project

```
iface.newProject()
```

### Add a layer

Whenever a new layer gets added to the mapcanvas, the welcome page will disappear

### Change the configuration

In contrast to the other two approaches, this changes the configuration of the QGIS installation permanently.

```
# 0: Welcome page
# 1: Most recent
# 2: Specific (specify with '/qgis/projOpenAtLaunchPath')
# 3: New
QSettings().setValue('/qgis/projOpenAtLaunch', 3)
```

Comment: Thank's Matthias!    if len(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()) == 0:      self.iface.newProject()  does the trick.

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Please be so kind and accept the answer as correct (there should be a green tick to click)